# Is there a double Positive equivalent to a negative?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

In logic and in standard English, a double negative is equivalent to a positive.

Is there a "double positive" equivalent to a negative?

My professor told me there is a double positive equal to a negative but i don't know it.

Comment: Yeah, yeah.  I've heard that one before.  But is this a mathematics question?

Comment: @kimchilover I think so, because I'm studying it in discrete-mathematics.

Comment: I'm not sure if it falls under discrete mathematics, but if you multiply two positive `i` then you get a negative number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number

Comment: @OblivionCreations thanks for that, can you give an example?

Comment: @user1058652 Oblivion Creations is talking about the imaginary unit, $i$. This is the number defined as $i * i = -1$. The complication here is that $i$ is neither positive or negative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"Yeah, yeah"**,
There is a famous story about philosopher once gave a talk in which he observed that whereas in English and many other languages a double negative is equivalent to a positive, there is no language in which a double positive is equivalent to a negative. To this, another philosopher, "Sidney Morgenbesser", responded sarcastically, **"Yeah, Yeah"**.

[Strictly speaking, sarcasm functions like negation. When spoken sarcasitaclly, the words "Yeah, Yeah" are not a true double positive; they just mean "no."]

Comment: Is there another example or it's this sentence only?

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question.

Comment: @ToddWilcox My answer was to prove that there is a "double positive" equivalent to a negative, Maybe someone will demonstrate it more deeply.

Answer (score 1):

To negate a statement is to deny it. The opposite of denying a statement is to affirm it. To deny a denial (a double negative) is to affirm. To affirm an affirmation (a "double positive?") is also to affirm.